# JavaScript: Type error theForm is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a price calculator where the user fills out a form and then the price for that is instantly calculated, but I'm getting this error where it says "Type error theForm is undefined". I've attached the image of my Javascript file thanks for anyhelp!

[image]

Comment: Stop use image for post code, please edit your question with work snippet code

Comment: Seems like js can't find this form.

Comment: please edit the question to also include the relevant html code that defines the form (paste as text, not image)

Comment: "form-horizontal" sounds like it's probably a CSS class name (from Bootstrap maybe?) 
rather than the ID of a form. So that's quite likely why it can't find it. There are ways to select an element by class name,  but if you want to identify one specific form, it would be better to use its ID. Also if you insist on using document.forms then to use the ID you have to write it like `document.forms.yourFormID` . Using `[]` means you're supposed to put a numeric index between the brackets e.g. `document.forms[0]` would find the the first form on the page.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation and examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

Comment: Also, as per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please it is hard to read/test code when it is provided in an image.

Regarding your problem I guess it is because your variable theForm is undefined when you try to access it.  Probably because the document.forms[] is an array waiting for a [numerical index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms). Hard to say as is.